# Create custom mode of ace-editor without requireJS

Tags: requirejs, ace-editor

I want to create an angular service module can generate custom mode of ace-editor. 
But for creating custom mode of ace-editor, it used requireJS. 
I don't want to use it in my angular service module. 
So I wonder how to create custom mode of ace-editor without requireJS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `ace.require` to get submodules from `ace.define` to register your mode with ace.

E.g this example http://plnkr.co/edit/HIFlsg889L4Z7dVYiV1y?p=info defines a mode without using requirejs

You can also create `MyModeConstructor` function in any way you want and then call
`ace.define("my/mode/id", [] {Mode:MyModeConstructor})`  to register it.